# 'if random.choice(x) = input(y)' doesn't execute the code below it

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and was having difficulty with a part of a program I made, here it is:

```
import random

with open ("sowpods.txt") as txt:
     words = txt.readlines()

word = random.choice(words)
print(word)
user_word = input("Word : ")
if user_word == word:
    print("You guessed correctly")
```

"sowpods.txt" is a file with words in it. I want the program to print "You guessed correctly" when the user guesses "word" correctly. However, nothing is printed. How can I fix this?

Thank you. :)

Comment: it sounds like you've guessed incorrectly every time

Comment: If `readlines()` returns a list of strings with trailing newline characters, the input won’t match.

Comment: I think `readlines` returns all the lines with a trailing newline character `\n` (except the last line if the file doesn't end with a newline) and `input` doesn't

Comment: change it to `if user_word.strip() == word.strip():` the first strip isn't strictly necessary, but if the user accidentally typed a space and the start or end of their input, you probably don't want to disqualify them immediately for that

Answer (score 4):

If this is the content of `sowpods.txt`:

```
fakher
mokadem
```

Then this code:

```
with open ("sowpods.txt") as txt:
     words = txt.readlines()
```

will fill the list `words` like this:

`['fakher \n', 'mokadem\n', '\n']`

Because even if you don't see them, '\n' and '[[space]]' are characters saved in the file, just like any other characters. When you use `print(word)` (or any other command or file reader to view the file content), print will interpret the new line and you will not distinguish the trailing spaces in the commandline.

[strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes whitespaces (leading and trailing) from the string, and the comparisons will not fail because of extra white spaces.

```
words = [word.strip() for word in txt]
```

Update: No need to call readlines in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
with open('sowpods.txt') as txt:
    for line in txt:
        print(line)
        word = random.choice(line.split())
        user_word = input('guess a word from above line: ')
        if user_word == word:
            print('You guessed correctly')
        else:
            print('better luck next line')
```

Comment: in your code, you were reading all lines i.e list of lines .....so you could not select an individual 'word' .... hence use split()

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```py
import random

with open(“sowpods.txt”, “r”) as fp:
    words = set(word.strip() for word in fp.readlines())

word = random.choice(words)
guess = “Bork”

while guess != word:
    guess = input("word: ")
print(“you guessed correctly”)
```